# Mongoose select not working?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here my schema :

```
var countries = new Schema({
name:  String,
capital: String,
body:   String,
flag: {data: Buffer, contentType: String },
population: String,
currency: String
      });
```

I want to select the fields name and capital.

Here my query:

```
countries.find({}, 'name capital', { skip: rand, limit: 1}, function(err, result){

              if (err) return handleError(err);

              console.log('Country :' + result);
              callback(null, result);

            });
```

But result print the entire document. 
result.name is undefined.

I tried different syntaxes, like

```
 countries.find({}, {'name':1, 'capital':1}, ....
```

But nothing is selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Please let me know otherwise.
If it did, feel free to accept it. That helps you, me and the rest of the community :)

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns an array of results, even though you limit it to 1.
That's probably why your `result.name` is `undefined`. So to access your `name` or `capital`, you have to use:

```
console.log("Country name:", result[0].name);
console.log("Country capital:", result[0].capital);
```

Maybe you want to use `findOne()`, which doesn't return an array but the object directly.

And both syntaxes should work, `name capital` and `{ name: 1, capital: 1 }`.